# linear layout alignment issue on device while rendering correctly on designer

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I have this code where I want 4 buttons to appear in given size and a textview to occupy the remaining space. this code while rendering correctly on android studio designer but on device it seems textview takes the wrapcontent property instead of layoutweight. did i miss anything?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bg_now_playing"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:background="@color/miniplayer_color"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <!--few components-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_controls"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/options"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/now_playing_extra_options_bg"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/nowplaying_favourites"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/nowplaying_icon_dimension"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/nowplaying_icon_dimension"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/nowplaying_button_padding"
                    android:src="@drawable/favorite_icon" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/download_btn"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/nowplaying_icon_dimension"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/nowplaying_icon_dimension"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/nowplaying_button_padding"
                    android:src="@drawable/download_icon" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/now_playing_share_btn"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/nowplaying_icon_dimension"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/nowplaying_icon_dimension"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/nowplaying_button_padding"
                    android:src="@drawable/share_icon" />

                <views.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/caller_tune"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundcorner_white"
                    android:fontFamily="@string/roboto_regular"
                    android:text="@string/tune"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/miniplayer_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/equalizer_now_playing"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/nowplaying_icon_dimension"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/nowplaying_icon_dimension"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/nowplaying_button_padding"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:src="@drawable/equalizer_icon" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!--few more components-->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be problem with your custom view. Because I placed just textview it worked fine. Here is my sample code with sample icons and metrics.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/bg_now_playing"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.7"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <!--few components-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_controls"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/options"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/nowplaying_favourites"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/download_btn"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/now_playing_share_btn"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

            <views.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/caller_tune"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/roundcorner_white"
                android:fontFamily="@string/roboto_regular"
                android:text="@string/tune"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/miniplayer_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/equalizer_now_playing"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--few more components-->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the parent layout of linear layout in your activity?

Comment: parent is Linear layout only. code snippet updated in the question.

Comment: I've edited the code above according to your new code. Please try again with this code. And can you please share your dimens values. Because as you can see I gave just sample width , height etc and its working fine again.